# How to relieve a rate-limited API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, rate-limiting

We run a website which heavily relies on the Amazon Product Advertising API (APAA). What happens is that when we experience a sudden spike in users it happens that we hit the rate-limit and all functions relying on the APAA shut down for a while. What can we do so that doesn't happen?

So, obviously we have some basic caching in place, but the APAA doesn't allow us to cache data for a very long time, and APAA queries can vary a lot so there may not be any cached data at all to query.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your only option is to retry the API calls until they work — but do so in a smart way. Unfortunately, that's what everybody that gets throttled does and AWS expects people to handle that themselves.

You can implement an exponential backoff and add jitter to prevent cluster calls. AWS has a great blog post about solutions for this kind of problem: https://www.awsarchitectureblog.com/2015/03/backoff.html